# UX Focus: Process vs Hands on?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed in job postings, books and conferences that there's a big focus on learning UX as a process that enables non-designers to deliver good UX.

I've also noticed that there's a lot of questions (including mine) that are more focused on the interface itself, rather than how to come with good ideas to generate good interfaces. Leave alone to make the user have a pleasant experience.

Is it valuable to pursue the *Process* over the *Specific Details/Fine Tune of UI design* on the site? If so, how can we help?

Comment: I think process is valuable and underrepresented on the site, but I'm not entirely sure how to encourage that.

Answer (score 1):

For the majority of users, easier questions, such as fine tuning of UI's works as a portal for this site. You come here, ask a specific question and get an (almost) imediate accurate answer. The more knowledge you gain, the more interested you'll be in the underlying process, user motivation, deep information architecture and an overall "feeling" of User Experience.

The more experienced users (me included) need to make answer in a more process kind of way, and not only deliver a short, simple and easy answer. Giving background to why things are as they are, maybe even historical changes will most certenly encourage less experienced ones of what makes not only a good, but complete answer.

When I can, and have the time, I'll continue to do so further on.